# How do I transform a columnar text file to XML?

Tags: xml, perl, jenkins-plugins, text-processing

I am trying to write a script to read from a text file and transform it to XML based on JUnit format. The text file output similar to this:

```
TEST                      TITLE                                    GROUP    PRIO R-STAT R-TIME       VERDICT  VERDICT-TEXT
------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------- ---- ------ ------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------
Telex                     Telex type                               GROUP1   1    PASS   00:00:02.914 PASS     Over
Time                      Timer                                    GROUP2   1    PASS   00:00:06.619 PASS     Over
```

Here is the output I expect for the text file above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites name="HostTests for Character" tests="TestSuite" time="">
<testsuite name="GROUP1" package="GROUP1" tests="" errors="">
<testcase classname="GROUP1.Telex" name="Telex type" time="" status="">
    <skipped/>
            <error message="" type=""/>
    <failure message="" type=""/>
    <system-out/>
            <system-err/>
        <testcase/>
<testcase classname="GROUP2.Time" name="Timer" time="" status="">
    <skipped/>
            <error message="" type=""/>
    <failure message="" type=""/>
    <system-out/>
            <system-err/>
<testcase/>
<textsuite/>
<testsuites/>
```

How can I write a Perl script to perform this in Jenkins?

I also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $textroot = $xslt ->parse_verdict_file("\\\~/jenkins/workspace/HostTestOAM/trunk/nash/test/regression/logs/verdict.1.txt");

my $checker = 1;
my @txtfile = logj('logs/verdict*.txt');
foreach (@txtfile){
my $txtfile = $_;
$txtfile =~ s/([ ()])/\\$1/g;
$txtroot2 = "\\\~/jenkins/workspace/HostTestOAM/trunk/nash/test/regression/logs/$txtfile";

my $source = $parser->parse_file($txtroot2);
    my $results = $textroot->transform($source);

my $xmlparsed = "\\\~/jenkins/workspace/HostTestOAM/trunk/nash/test/regression/logs/results$checker.xml";

unless(open FILE, '>'.$xmlparsed) {
die "\Creating failed\n";
}

$textroot -> output_file($results, FILE);
close FILE;
$checker++;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some sort of code that you tried to implement.  People aren't going to just do it for you.  I understand that it may be difficult if you have no idea what you're doing, but start off with a basic example and work your way up.

Comment: I am sorry about my mistake. Below is the code which i tried:

Comment: I editted above Steve :)

Comment: Why do you use XML parser? All you need is to parse text file, and then you can print XML manually.

Comment: What i want to print to a XML file following the format in this link http://junitpdfreport.sourceforge.net/managedcontent/PdfTranslation 
You mean there is manual way to perform this, right?

Comment: Is there any comment or idea to help me?

Comment: He's saying that if you know the format of your output, you can simply extract the necessary values from your text document and insert them in some large print statement(s), thereby manually generating your .xml.  Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that what you need to do is build a template for how you want your XML to look, and put in placeholders for the bits that could change.  Say,

```
my $template = '<testsuite name="XXXGROUPXXX" package="XXXGROUPXXX" tests="" errors="">
<testcase classname="XXXGROUPXXX.XXXTESTXXX" name="XXXTITLEXXX" time="" status="">';
```

Next, you have to read in your file of tabular data, which is easy in Perl: the usual idiom.  (To save time I'm not writing grammatical Perl here...)

```
open(IN, $file);
while ($line = <IN>)
{
  chomp($line);
  # skip noise, blanks: next if (blah)
  # Now split the line into fields so you can extract what you need
  ($test, $title, $group, $the_rest) = split($line); 

  # and substitute the values read for test, title, group into a template
  # rinse and repeat;
  ($foo = $template) =~ s/XXXGROUPXXX/$group);


  #print the new text out
  print $foo;
}
close(IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i tried another way, i think it is good. Below is code lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Writer;
use XML::Simple;

my $file = 'logs/verdict*.txt';

my %testsuite = (testcase => [
{classname => 'CELL.NbapCellDelete', name => 'Cell deletion', time => '%file',          status => '%file'},]
);
my $xmlObj = XML::Simple->new(RootName => 'testsuite');
print $xmlObj->XMLout (\%testsuite, noattr => 1, xmldecl => => '<?xml version="1.0"      encoding="UTF-8"?>');
```

The problem is at time and status, my idea is create a dynamic array or dynamic hash to store time and status into, then push them into the xml file, maybe compare the value between that dynamic array and variables. could you please help?